# javascript scroll back to the top

Tags: javascript

how can I get this scroll back to the top neat thing from [this link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementmethods.shtml) , just scroll down a bit, you'll see in the bottom right icon(top pointer) that scrolls back to the top on click. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the script here:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/jkincludes/scrolltopcontrol.js

Although you need to use jquery for this script to work.

Answer (score 4):

In jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a[href=#top]').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });

});
```

You can then make links like this:

```
<a href="#top" title="Scroll back to the top">Back to the top</a>
```